# Two definitions of double categories?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

A **double category** can be defined as a category object in $\mathbf{Cat}$ the category of small categories.

We can also define a double category as four categories satisfying some compatibility conditions.

Can anyone recommend me a reference where I can find the equivalence between those two approachs?

Some time ago I've found a paper in french that worked out the details but I ended up losing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I remember some clear proof about what you say was in the famous paper by Wadhausen, in his paper about the S-construction: try to get his paper: Algebraic K-Theory of Generalized Free Products, Part 1, Annals of Mathematics. There is a whole part pretty clear about the basic properties of double categories.

PS I should add that Waldhausen calls "bicategories" what we call nowdays "double categories". His paper is from 1978, and the terminology was not yet completely accepted. However, his bicategories are precisely what now are called "double categories".

Comment: I could also recommend the works of Grandis and Paré.